# Using websockets in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Is there any way to use websockets in tomcat 6 (business requirement)?

I've been trying using javax.websocket.jar but I can't get it to work

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echoAnnotation")
public class EchoAnnotation {    @OnMessage
     public void echoTextMessage(Session session, String msg, boolean last) {
          try {
               if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg, last);
               }
          } catch (IOException e) {
               try {
                    session.close();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // Ignore
               }
          }
     }

}
```

And my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5"> 

    <description>
      Servlet and JSP Examples.
    </description>
    <display-name>Servlet and JSP Examples</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>echoAnnotation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>EchoAnnotation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>echoAnnotation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/echoAnnotation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However I cannot make a websocket connection, I get an error message `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://192.168.1.101:8080/prototypes/echoAnnotation` and going directly to the page results in `HTTP Status 404 - Servlet echoAnnotation is not available`

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems `EchoAnnotation` is not recognized as a servlet, as it doesn't extend any servlet type.

Comment: Right, that's because I used the sample for javax.websocket and it uses annotation that's supported in later versions of tomcat, or glassfish but not tomcat 6.

Answer (score 3):

As I found tomcat 6 doesn't support Java WebSockets. See http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html